# yii2 POST parameters mapping

Tags: php, mapping, yii2

i have some js script that send simular data:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/manage/add-shops/',
        data: {'id':id, 'shops': shops}
```

'shops' is array with ~1000 elements, so i should send it via POST.
I have a yii2 Controller with method:

```
class ManageController extends Controller {
    public function actionAddShops($id, $shops=array()) {
       ....
    }
```

Routing is Ok, but i get this error:

```
"Missing required parameters: id"
```

It's look like that POST params doesn't mapped to method params.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there is no native POST mapping, but we can implement it, like this:

```
class OurUrlRule extends UrlRule implements UrlRuleInterface {
    public function parseRequest($manager, $request, $add_post = true, $add_files = true) {
        $result = parent::parseRequest($manager, $request);
        if($result !== false) {
            list($route, $params) = $result;
            if($add_post    === true) {
                $params = array_merge($params,$_POST);
            }
            if($add_files   === true) {
                $params = array_merge($params,$_FILES);
            }
            return [$route, $params];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then, add to routes:

```
['pattern'=>'manage/<action:\S+>', 'route'=>'manage/<action>', 'suffix'=>'/', 'class' => 'app\components\OurUrlRule',]
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is just plain wrong. Yii has always implemented post mapping, and continues to do so. See here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#post%28%29-detail

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, I meant POST mapping directly to called method.

Comment: I see what you mean now. How about calling a separate function then with the post data passed as method parameters? That could achieve what you want.

Answer (score 8):

You are right, for some reason, Yii2 only automatically binds GET variables, but unfortunately not POST.

However, you can easily do the magic binding; all you have to do is to override the `runAction()` of your controller. If you don't want to do it manually for every controller, just create a base controller and extend from it when required. Check the following snippet:

```
public function runAction($id, $params = [])
{
    // Extract the params from the request and bind them to params
    $params = \yii\helpers\BaseArrayHelper::merge(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), $params);
    return parent::runAction($id, $params);
}
```

Then you will be able to access in your controller action `$id` and `$shops` normally as you used to do in Yii1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add to your controller:

```
public function bindActionParams($action, $params)
{
    return array_merge($params, Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams());
}
```

and actionAddShops will receive $id and $shops from post body.

Answer (score -1):

When you pass parameters to a controller action, those parameters are only available if they are in the GET of a url. If you are sending parameters by POST, then you will need to access them via the Yii::$app->request->post method.

so your function ends up looking something like this;

```
enter class ManageController extends Controller {
public function actionAddShops() {
   $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
   $id = $post['id'];
   $shops = $post['shops'];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: May I ask why you would want to avoid doing this? It seems to me the most efficient way of getting data to your controller.

Comment: Cause it's more simpler to write `function actionAny($i,$j,$k)` instead of `function actionAny() { $post = Yii::$app->request->post(); if(!isset($post['i'] === null) { return false; } else {$i = $post['i'];}` and so on...

Comment: In that case @Arkham.vm your answer is no. Yii only maps action parameters from the GET part of a url. Post data is only available from Yii::$app->request->post(); unless you roll your own function like you have below. May I suggest though, that if your action requires so detailed a knowledge of how your data is arranged, that you'd be better delegating some of the functionality to the model, rather than leaving it to the controller.

Answer (score -2):

```
class ManageController extends Controller {
    public function actionAddShops() {
       var_dump($_POST);
    }
```

Here you go.

Comment: There is any automatic POST mapping?

Comment: You can use JSON instead of POST.

Comment: It's Ok for JS script, but what if it's a standart POST <form>?

Comment: The input name argument will be a key for a $_POST array. For example if name="foo", $_POST['foo'] will contain the value. Name = "foo[bar]", $_POST["foo"]["bar"] == value.

Comment: So I can only do it manually, and there is no automatic POST mapping?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean then say mapping? Можно по русски.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69795/discussion-between-vick-and-arkham-vm).

Answer (score -2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/manage/add-shops/',
    data: {'id':id, 'shops': shops}

class ManageController extends Controller {
public function actionAddShops($id, $shops=array()) {
   ....
}
```

What i have understand from your code is you are passing values through ajax using POST method but if your are using an action method in your controller with parameters then it means this action needs GET method for use. So simply change your ajax method to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/manage/add-shops/',
    data: {'id':id, 'shops': shops}
```

And then check it will work perfectly.

Comment: The poster has said that 'shops' could be an array of ~1000 values, so this would not be appropriate to send via GET.

Comment: I can understand but according to his controller i have changed the code.